# Python concatenate timestamp to list elements

Tags: python, list, timestamp, concatenation, element

I want to concatenate timestamp to individual list elements to create a txt or csv file.
Here's the code I tried which is concatenating the timestamp to the last element only. So I am doing it wrong. Appreciate any help. Thanks

The expected output is

BSTG,2022-01-13 22:09:07

XTLB,2022-01-13 22:09:07

SERA,2022-01-13 22:09:07

SIDU,2022-01-13 22:09:07

RPID,2022-01-13 22:09:07

BBLN,2022-01-13 22:09:07

SGLY,2022-01-13 22:09:07

DAVE,2022-01-13 22:09:07

GMVD,2022-01-13 22:09:07

BBIG,2022-01-13 22:09:07

```
# Code Begin
from datetime import datetime

current_results = ['BSTG,XTLB,SERA,SIDU,RPID,BBLN,SGLY,DAVE,GMVD,BBIG']

now = datetime.now()
print(current_results)

for elem in current_results:
    print(str(elem)+str(now))

#Code End
```

Comment: Is it intentional that current_results is a list with 1 string instead of a list of multiple strings?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two problems here that I notice:

#### 1

```
current_results = ['BSTG,XTLB,SERA,SIDU,RPID,BBLN,SGLY,DAVE,GMVD,BBIG']
```

is a list with just one `str` element.

Instead you may want to use:

```
current_results = ['BSTG', 'XTLB', 'SERA', 'SIDU' , 'RPID', 'BBLN', 'SGLY', 'DAVE', 'GMVD', 'BBIG']
```

#### 2

When you concatenate results the comma is missing. You may want to use f-strings https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/ to format the CSV output easily.

```
print(f"{elem},{now}")
```

There are csv specific libraries, e.g. built-in `csv` but for such a simple case they could be an overkill.

Comment: `print(elem, now, sep=",")`, but better to use `csv` module to write CSV file.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is `current_list` is a list of 1 element which you need to process before looping:

```
from datetime import datetime

current_results = ['BSTG,XTLB,SERA,SIDU,RPID,BBLN,SGLY,DAVE,GMVD,BBIG']

now = datetime.now()
print(current_results)
# get the current_results and convert them to a list
current_results = current_results[0].split(',')
# now we can loop and concatenate the time stamp to each result
for res in current_results:
    res = res + ',' + now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
    print(res)
```

Answer (score 0):

The `current_results` attribute is a `list` that contains a single `str` on it. You can parse your list into a list with every element separated, like this:

```py
from datetime import datetime

current_results = ['BSTG,XTLB,SERA,SIDU,RPID,BBLN,SGLY,DAVE,GMVD,BBIG']
parsed_results = current_results[0].split(",")

now = datetime.now()
print(current_results)

for elem in parsed_results:
    print(str(elem)+str(now))
```

The `parsed_results = current_results[0].split(",")` will do the trick!